# Scroll effect from Nav to specific sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get my code to scroll so that when the user clicks on the nav links it scrolls to that section in particular. I can't figure out what line of code is wrong because when I click it does take me to the section it just doesn't scroll.

```js
$('.scroll-to').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var thisTarget = $(this).attr('href');
  var targetOffset = $(thisTarget).offset().top;
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: targetOffset
  }, 600);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navigation">
  <section>
    <div class="navlinks">
      <a href="#about" class="scroll-to">about</a>
      <a href="3skills" class="scroll-to">skills</a>
      <a href="#work" class="scroll-to">work</a>
      <a href="#youtube" class="scroll-to">youtube</a>
      <a href="#recommendation" class="scroll-to">recommendations</a>
      <a href="#contactform" class="scroll-to">contact</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your above code works as expected; there can only be two things that are possibly wrong:

- You have not included jQuery
- You do not have an element with an `ID` corresponding to the target

Also note that an element **cannot** start with an ID, so your `3skills` element will never be able to scroll. I **assume** this was simply a typo for the hash, so I've changed it to `#skills`.

Adding the links and ensuring that they don't start with numbers produces a working example, as is seen below:

```js
$('.scroll-to').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var thisTarget = $(this).attr('href');
  var targetOffset = $(thisTarget).offset().top;
  
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: targetOffset
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
#about {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="navlinks">
  <a href="#about" class="scroll-to">about</a>
  <a href="#skills" class="scroll-to">skills</a>
  <a href="#work" class="scroll-to">work</a>
  <a href="#youtube" class="scroll-to">youtube</a>
  <a href="#recommendation" class="scroll-to">recommendations</a>
  <a href="#contactform" class="scroll-to">contact</a>
</div>

<div id="about">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="skills">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="work">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="youtube">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="recommendation">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="contactform">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Hope this helps!